# Drive damaged during VMWare copy

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, vmware, disk

I was copying data from two ext2 formatted drives using an Ubuntu 11.04 Virtual Machine in VMWare  Fusion 4 on a MacMini with Snow Leopard. I meant to quit from something else, but accidentally quit Fusion mid copy.  Now the two drives will not mount.  "Unable to mount" "Error mounting: mount:wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2, missing codepage or helper program or other error.  In some cases useful info is found in syslog - t try dmesg | tail or so"
All dmesg produces is:
"Write Protect is off
Mode Sense: 00 38 00 00
Asking for cache data failed
Assuming drive cache: write through
Asking for cache data failed
Assuming drive cache: write through
sdc: sdc1 sdc2
Asking for cache data failed
Assuming drive cache write through
Attached SCSI disk"

I need the data on this disk, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a bootable recovery tool like Paragon Rescue Kit - Free Edition. I've never used it, but it claims to have the ability to recover data from paritions that have been deleted. It supports the following file systems: NTFS (v1.2, v3.0, v3.1), FAT16/FAT32, Ext2FS/Ext3FS/Ext4FS, Linux Swap, HPFS (only view), Apple HFS+, and Backup Capsule.

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-express/